# How can you create a preview window for seamless tile editing in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tiles

Here's an example: https://youtu.be/ooo51ZRgU_4?t=351

I want to be able to just save the image on the right which will update the picture on the left. This could be done with smart objects I guess, but that's not the case in the Jazza's video. I'm baffled.

I know there are some other solutions, but I want it to work just like in the video. Pressing save updates the image on the left.

For those looking for similar solutions: Pyxel Edit has similar kind of functionality and it's the best.

Comment: No jaza uses smart objects. Just linked them from disk

Comment: He is using Smart Objects - you can see him working on the psb, while the main document is open on the left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to work on seamless tiles using *Smart Objects*.

Let's say that we want to do a 16x16 px tile. We only really need to see it repeated 3x3 times to check if the pattern works so we'll stick to that for this example, but you can of course make it as large as you want.

- Create a 48x48 px document.
- Create a new layer and fill a 16x16 px rectangle in the top left corner.
- Select the layer, right-click and *Convert to Smart Object*.
- Use *Move Tool* while holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> to drag eight copies of the Smart Object filling up the document.
- All of the copied Smart Objects are references to the same original Smart Object, so now you can double-click the thumbnail of any of them to start editing a single tile in a separate window.
- Set up the split screen with *Window > Arrange > 2-up Vertical* and you are good to go! Whenever you save the Smart Object, the main document will update.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick and detailed response. Even more points from the gif below. I managed to create this with only one updating tile, but copying them that way seems to be easy and fast solution to link all the references succesfully.. Hopefully this comes handy for the others too. I couldn't find one single video tutorial from YT that would have explained this workflow and you did it as efficiently as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you liked it! Especially the gif - it sure took some trial and error to make . I tried to find a more automatized way to copy the tiles, but ended up just Alt+dragging them. It shouldn't take too long no matter how many you want if you keep doubling the tiles for each drag (1-2-4-8-16-32-64-128 etc.).