# Linking multiple layers to the same smart object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

I have a sketch with hundreds of identical squares in separate layers. Now, I want to edit every square in the same way - let's say I want to give them a funny hat - without having to edit them one at a time. Is it possible to do this in Photoshop? Could smart objects provide a solution?

I understand the squares can be turned into separate smart objects, which can then be edited one at a time. Or you can put them all together in a single smart object. But is it possible to link them all to a smart object with just one single square in it, so that you can edit them all at once?

Alternatively, if you know a different way to achieve the same result I would be interested in that as well.

I use Photoshop CS4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update multiple duplicates of the same image in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/132424/how-to-update-multiple-duplicates-of-the-same-image-in-photoshop)

Comment: This is also related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/131457

Comment: They don't answer my question, because I start from a point where the squares aready exist but aren't linked to smart objects. They are simply identical squares in separate layers. I want to find away to link them to a single smart object. I have noticed that if I turn them all into separate smart objects, I can then replace them individually so that they point to the same object. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to replace them all at once. Replacing them individually would be cumbersome.

Comment: I think replacing them separately is the only solution. You should have made them duplicates of the same smart object from the beginning.